# Index return the first letter of the destination value instead of the target value

Tags: python, pandas

I use this code to pull API Data names from an Exchange and they retrieve their equivalent symbol, but my current problem is that I suspect that the index returned is correct because when I look for the associated symbol, I get the first letter of the name and not the symbol.

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI
import pandas as pd

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
response_list = cg.get_coins_list()

response_list_normalized = pd.json_normalize(response_list)
print('\n--- selected: LIST NORMALIZED ---')
print(response_list_normalized)

response_list_stringed = ''.join(map(str, response_list_normalized['name']))
if crypto_token_name in response_list_stringed:
    print('\n--- selected: EXACT MATCHING RESULT ---')
    print('Found it!')

    position = response_list_stringed.index('Cardano')
    print('\n--- position: INDEX ---')
    print(position)

    symbol = response_list_stringed[position]
    print('\n--- position: SYMBOL ---')
    print(symbol)
else:
    print('\n--- selected: LIST MATCHING RESULT ---')
    print('Not found! :(')
```

Is the list dimension in cause, or am I pointing to the wrong target? I spent days trying every possible variant to get it to look for the name and retrieve its index and associated symbol.

Comment: I'm unclear. You make a string with no spaces out of the collection -> `''.join(map(str, response_list_normalized['name']))` Something like `"thisisastring"` then iterate over each character in that string `if crypto_token_name in response_list_stringed` yielding `t`, `h`, `i`, ... etc. What were you trying to do?

Comment: @HenryEcker , I start by pulling the API Data, then normalize it so I can use a search function to retrieve the symbol for each name I insert. You can try the above code, it will run right away and you can see the log it gives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it fixed with `index = response_list_normalized[response_list_normalized['name'] ==crypto_token_name].index.values`